# How to access an object from another class in python oop?

Tags: python, oop

I am currently working on the "3.2.1.16 Queue aka FIFO: part 2" lab from edube:

> Your task is to slightly extend the Queue class' capabilities. We want
> it to have a parameterless method that returns True if the queue is
> empty and False otherwise.
>
> Complete the code we've provided in the editor. Run it to check
> whether it outputs a similar result to ours.
>
> Below you can copy the code we used in the previous lab.

My code so far is as follows (I have copied the code for the Queue class and my task is now to work on the SuperQueue class):

```
class QueueError(IndexError):
    pass


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
    def put(self,elem):
        self.queue.insert(0,elem)
    def get(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            elem = self.queue[-1]
            del self.queue[-1]
            return elem
        else:
            raise QueueError


class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        Queue()
    def isempty(self):
        if len(Queue.self.queue)==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        


que = SuperQueue()
que.put(1)
que.put("dog")
que.put(False)
for i in range(4):
    if not que.isempty():
        print(que.get())
    else:
        print("Queue empty")
```

The crucial point is the `if len(Queue.self.queue)==0`. This does not work. What I want to do is to check if the length of the queue is zero. However, the queue is stored as an object in the other class. So how can I access it from the SuperQueue class?

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about inheritance is that a class, well, inherits: as in "owns directly", as part of itself. There's no such thing as `Queue.self.queue` for the child instance. The instance has a single namespace dictionary, so

```
if len(self.queue) == 0:
```

Also, get rid of the initializer in `SuperQueue`: if all you're doing is calling the parent `__init__`, you can let the parent implementation take care of it directly. If you need other functionality, call the parent method correctly:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

This is python, not Java. The current implementation just calls `Queue()`, which creates a new instance of the parent class without initializing this one, and discards that instance immediately as the method exits.

Finally, keep in mind that virtually all python objects have a boolean value. You can rewrite the `isempty` method as a one liner. That makes `SuperQueue` super simple:

```
class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def isempty(self):
        return not self.queue
```

Comment: Could you post a full working code? When I try to adapt it (with the if len(self.queue) == 0: solution, not return not) and I get the error message: AttributeError: 'SuperQueue' object has no attribute 'queue'

Comment: @BertHobe. Did you fix `__init__`?

Comment: I tried it with fixing __init__. I tried different variants but I get an error as I mentioned or I get syntax error. Somewhere I did a mistake, but I don't know where.

Comment: @BertHobe. I clarified what I mean about `__init__`. Your best option is still to just delete that method entirely and let `Queue.__init__` do the work

Comment: I do not get it working. Could you maybe post a full working example for the first solution and for the other (Queue.__init__)?

Comment: @BertHobe. Just updated. Where exactly is the error?

Comment: When I use the solution with def __init__(self):
    super().__init__() it does not work?

Comment: @BertHobe. Should work fine. Which class are you modifying? You shouldn't touch `Queue`

Comment: Yes I know, I just tried to modify SuperQueue(Queue). Also I wonder about the super(). This was not mentioned in the course so far. So there must be another, more simpler solution?

Comment: @BertHobe. You can replace `super().__init__()` with `Queue.__init__(self)`

Comment: @BertHobe. Added clarification. Let me know if you still see errors

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to get your code running. When I try to implement the code you posted I get error message.

Comment: What version of python? What error?

Comment: I use the python from the edube console. I get the error message: AttributeError: 'SuperQueue' object has no attribute 'queue'.

Comment: I also don't understand how it works with the inheritance and the child. But actually I would like to understand it.

Comment: If you're calling `super.__init__()` you're initializing the `queue`. `__init__` is just a regular method. If you call a version that initializes an empty list in `self`, that's what it'll do, regardless of what `self` is

Comment: But there must be a solution without using super? This was not mentioned in the course so far. So actually students should not know this super.

Comment: @BertHobe. I showed you two ways without super. Best is to get rid of init. The other is in the comments

Answer (score -1):

````
class QueueError(IndexError):
    pass


class Queue:`enter code here`
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
    def put(self,elem):
        self.queue.insert(0,elem)
    def get(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            elem = self.queue[-1]
            del self.queue[-1]
            return elem
        else:
            raise QueueError
    


class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def isempty(self):
        return not self.queue
    


que = SuperQueue()
que.put(1)
que.put("dog")
que.put(False)
for i in range(4):
    if not que.isempty():
        print(que.get())
    else:
        print("Queue empty")```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).